# Geo choropleth map and pie chart crossfiltering using dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

With the code I want to be able to click on any state and the pie chart should depict the number of males and females in that state.

### gender.csv is of the following pattern

```
gender,age,state
Male,9,1
Male,10,1
Male,18,2
Male,20,0
Male,22,1
Male,30,1
Male,40,1
Male,45,2
Male,50,2
Male,55,2
Male,70,0
Male,80,0
Male,90,0
Male,100,0
Male,101,0
Female,11,0
Female,15,0
Female,20,0
```

### us-states.json is of the following pattern

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"AL"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}},`

### code

```
d3.csv("data/gender.csv", function (data) {
            d3.json("data/us-states.json", function (json){


                var ndx = crossfilter(data);

                var stateDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.state; });
                var genderDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.gender; });
                var ageDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.age; });

                var state = stateDim.group();
                var gender = genderDim.group(); 
                var age = ageDim.group();

                var pie = dc.pieChart('#pie');
                var usmap = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#map");

                //create pie to show gender
                pie
                    .width(180)
                    .height(180)
                    .radius(80)
                    .dimension(genderDim)
                    .group(gender)
                    .renderLabel(true)
                    .innerRadius(10)
                    .transitionDuration(500)
                    .colorAccessor(function (d, i) { return d.value; });

                //display US map                    
                usmap
                    .width(900)
                    .height(500)
                    .dimension(stateDim)
                    .group(state)
                    .colors(["rgb(20,202,255)","rgb(144,211,035)"])
                    .overlayGeoJson(json.features, "name", function (d) { return d.properties.name; })      


                // at the end this needs to be called to actually go through and generate all the graphs on the page.
                dc.renderAll();
            }); 
        });
```

When I am clicking on any state, the pie chart is showing empty. Also the tooltips on the map are showing the state initials and undefined, for example: `AL: undefined`

Where am I going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a working example (e.g. a jsfiddle or block) but it looks like states are indicated with numbers in your data, but abbreviations in the map?

Comment: @Gordon In the fiddle I cannot include the data sheets it seems.

Comment: @Gordon what you said helped. Changing the numbers to abbreviations. Thanks!

Comment: Great! For next time, here's the trick for putting data in your fiddle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22890836/676195

Comment: @Gordon Could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912279/how-to-put-data-ranges-in-piecharts-using-dc-js ?